# Duda con new Date Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

me gustaria saber si alguien puede explicarme lo que hace la variable difference ? No logro comprender lo que estaria restando y dividiendo, logro comprender mas o menos la logica, pero que numeros entrarian ahi? muchas gracias.

```js
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var est = new Date("Feb 16, 1996 15:45:55");
var difference = today.getTime() - est.getTime();
difference = (difference / 31556900000);

var elMSG = document.getElementById("message");
elMSG.textContent = Math.floor(difference) + " years of online travel advice";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 
 <footer id = "message"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la primera aparición de difference:

```
var difference = today.getTime() - est.getTime();
```

Considerando que getTime() lo que hace es convertir una variable de tipo Date() a milisegundos (desde el 1 de Enero de 1970 a las 00:00:00), se está calculando la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos entre la fecha de la var today (Este momento) y la fecha de la var est (Feb 16, 1996 15:45:55).

Luego en la segunda aparición de difference:

```
difference = (difference / 31556900000);
```

Lo que hace es dividir por 31556900000 que es la cantidad de milisegundos que tiene un año, es decir está mostrando la diferencia antes descrita en años en lugar de milisegundos.

Finalmente Math.floor lo trunca hacia abajo.

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Gracias genio, lo termine de entender, gracias por tu tiempo,saludos.